# Validate that exactly one input is filled

Tags: javascript, loops, validation

I have the following code (take a look at the snippet) that runs a `forEach` on an Array to look if there is an empty input and add a CSS class. It must "flag" if all of them are empty, or if more than two inputs are filled.

The process that I want to do, it should require exactly **only one** of the three to be filled and the other two to be empty before save.

```
    Case A:
    
    optionA: filled
    optionB: empty
    optionC: empty
    
    Result Save: true.
    
    Case B:
    
    optionA: filled
    optionB: empty
    optionC: filled
    
    Result Save: false.


    Case C:
    
    optionA: empty
    optionB: empty
    optionC: empty
    
    Result Save: false.
```

```js
const save = document.getElementById("save");

save.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];

  fields.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).value == "") {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
    } else {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.remove("alertField");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.alertField {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#save {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <form>
   <label for="optionA">Option A:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionA" name="optionA"><br><br>
   <label for="optionB">Option B:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionB" name="optionB"><br><br>
   <label for="optionC">Option C:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionC" name="optionC"><br><br>
   <div id="save">Save</div>
 </form>
```

I'm wondering if there exists some array method to do that.

PS: Also can take a look on my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yasserpulido/pen/xxZyadd?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goal: The process that I want to do, it should require exactly **only one** of the three to be filled and the other two to be empty before save.

```
Case A:

optionA: filled
optionB: empty
optionC: empty

Result Save: true.

Case B:

optionA: filled
optionB: empty
optionC: filled

Result Save: false.

Case C:

optionA: empty
optionB: empty
optionC: empty

Result Save: false.
```

```js
const save = document.getElementById("save");

 // Next method require only one input be filled.

saveOne.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];
  let fieldsFilled = [];
  let count = 0;

  var allEmpty = fields.every(function (element) {
    return document.getElementById(element).value == "";
  });

  if (allEmpty) {
    fields.forEach(function (element) {
      if (document.getElementById(element).value == "") {
        document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
      }
    });
  } else {
    fields.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      if (document.getElementById(element).value != "") {
        fieldsFilled.push(element);
        document.getElementById(element).classList.remove("alertField");
      } else {
        document.getElementById(element).classList.remove("alertField");
      }
    });

    fieldsFilled.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      if (fieldsFilled.length > 1) {
        document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
        count = count + 1;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  height: 100vh;
}

form {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #c0392b;
}

.alertField {
  border: 4px solid #c0392b;
}

input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.save {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #2980b9;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <p>The following form has three input type text that receives data.</p>
  
  <label for="optionA">Option A:</label>
  <input type="text" id="optionA" name="optionA"><br><br>
  <label for="optionB">Option B:</label>
  <input type="text" id="optionB" name="optionB"><br><br>
  <label for="optionC">Option C:</label>
  <input type="text" id="optionC" name="optionC"><br><br>
  
  <p>The following button "Save Only One" works as a validation, where only one input has to be filled</p>
  
  <input id="saveOne" class="save" value="Save Only One" type="sumbit"/>
  
  <p>It is used with Array methods instead of if-else conditional, because it could be a case when exits more than one inputs text.</p>
  
</form>
```

What was learning about this problem?

The knowledge about apply validations with `array` methods.

Why did the problem occur?

Job situation where dynamic table generates a lot of inputs and it was solved about that moment with a lot of `if-else` conditional.

That is why I was wondering it could be solved too in another way, I thought in arrays because the dynamic table generate id by input.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to prevent users from entring text which is what I understood from your question, you could listen to the event of the fields you want to restrict and both fields will light up red, the last field will be red only if it's empty otherwise the alert class will be removed.

**Note**:**preventing user from entering text in the input field is not a good user experience**

```js
  const save = document.getElementById("save");
  const field1 = document.getElementById("optionA");
  const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
 if(e.target.name=="optionA"||e.target.name=="optionB")
   e.preventDefault()
   if(e.target.name=="optionC"){
    e.target.classList.remove("alertField")
  }
});

save.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];

  fields.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).value == "") {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
    } else {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.remove("alertField");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.alertField {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#save {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <form id="form">
   <label for="optionA">Option A:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionA" name="optionA"><br><br>
   <label for="optionB">Option B:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionB" name="optionB"><br><br>
   <label for="optionC">Option C:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionC" name="optionC"><br><br>
   <div id="save">Save</div>
 </form>
```

If the purpose from your question is to switch the alert class between fields when the field is empty you could do something like this

```js
const save = document.getElementById("save");
  const field1 = document.getElementById("optionA");
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if(e.target.name=="optionC"||e.target.name=="optionA"||e.target.name=="optionB"){
    e.target.classList.remove("alertField")
  }
});

save.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];

  fields.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).value == "") {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
    } else {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.remove("alertField");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.alertField {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#save {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <form id="form">
   <label for="optionA">Option A:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionA" name="optionA"><br><br>
   <label for="optionB">Option B:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionB" name="optionB"><br><br>
   <label for="optionC">Option C:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionC" name="optionC"><br><br>
   <div id="save">Save</div>
 </form>
```

Comment: @AndrewMyers well that's what OP wants I assume it's only for learning propose though not a real life project

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I understand your concern, but OP was specific in what he wants, obviously in a real life you can't prevent users from entering does,who does that!!! it's just silly.But I think it's for learning proposes, if you feel that his question is not just you could use flag and I am pretty sure a moderator will make the necessary call

Comment: No need for CAPITAL letters, and I have updated my answer, i think this conversation is no more productive

Comment: @Here my upvote for you. You did the right thing. Good on you.

Comment: I think my english is not good enough. But I just want to alert when more than one input is filled. I will update ny post, because in the real problem I have more than 10 input, and all the validation is doing with conditional if-else, and I want to "optimize" using an array for example, running each input and verify is empty or no, and also making sure that only one is filled.

Answer (score 1):

[Sven.hig has a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946311/5764553), but here's how you could do this if you don't try to stop invalid input.

What I'm doing is looping through the inputs twice. The first loop is to get a count of inputs with data. The second loop only happens if there is not exactly one input with data.

Your original code has a `forEach` loop, and that's fine. You can get a count with that, but this is the sort of thing [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) was made for. (I will admit, though, that it's hard to remember how to use `reduce` - I have to look up the documentation almost every time.)

The code below should fulfill your requirements. If there are no values supplied, all fields will be highlighted. If more than one is given a value, then only the fields that have values will be highlighted.

```js
const save = document.getElementById("save");

save.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];
  
  let counter = fields.reduce(function (count, element) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).value === "") {
      return count;
    }
    return count + 1;
  }, 0);
  
  if (counter < 1) {
    fields.forEach(function (element) {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
    });
  } else if (counter > 1) {
    fields.forEach(function (element) {
      if (document.getElementById(element).value !== "") {
        document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
      }
    });
  }
  
});
```

```css
.alertField {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#save {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <label for="optionA">Option A:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionA" name="optionA"><br><br>
   <label for="optionB">Option B:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionB" name="optionB"><br><br>
   <label for="optionC">Option C:</label>
   <input type="text" id="optionC" name="optionC"><br><br>
   <div id="save">Save</div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Your example allowed me know about others existing array methods that I can use with JS. First, I used ```array.every``` to get if all inputs are empty. Then, I used a ```if-else``` contidion where works depends on the ```array.every``` result. Inside the conditionals ```if-else```, I used ```forEach``` methods and also ```array.push```. At result, I got what I want, and fulfill the three cases that you can take a look on my problem post.

Answer (score 0):

What about just adding a counter on how many fields have values, if there's only one then continue.

```
const save = document.getElementById("save");

save.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];
  let fieldsWithValue = 0;
  fields.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).value == "") {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.add("alertField");
    } else {
      document.getElementById(element).classList.remove("alertField");
      fieldsWithValue++;
    }
  });
  if (fieldsWithValue == 1) {
    //valid
  }
  else {
    //invalid
  }
});
```

Comment: It should flag the inputs, if they are all empty or more than two filled.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const save = document.getElementById("save");

save.addEventListener("click", function() {

      let fields = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"];
      let inputs = [];
      let hasVal = [];
      fields.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        let input = document.getElementById(element);
        input.classList.remove("alertField");
        inputs.push(input);
        if (input.value == "") {
          hasVal.push(false);
        } else {
          hasVal.push(true);
        }
      });

      let count = hasVal.filter(Boolean).length;

      if (!count) {
        inputs.forEach(input => input.classList.add("alertField"));
        }
        else if (count > 1) {
          inputs.forEach(input => {
            if (input.value) {
              input.classList.add("alertField");
            }
          })
        } else {
          // form.submit();
        }
      });
```

```css
.alertField {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

#save {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="optionA">Option A:</label>
  <input type="text" id="optionA" name="optionA"><br><br>
  <label for="optionB">Option B:</label>
  <input type="text" id="optionB" name="optionB"><br><br>
  <label for="optionC">Option C:</label>
  <input type="text" id="optionC" name="optionC"><br><br>
  <div id="save">Save</div>
</form>
```